# Link individual songs from mediaelement.js playlist

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, mediaelement.js

I'm using MediaElement.js playlist option and would like to be able create links to individual songs. For example, I'd use it in a CodeIgniter site as *briansukovez.com/audio/summertime/2* which should play second song.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
$current = $this->uri->segment(3);
echo "$(function(){
$('audio,video').mediaelementplayer({
loop: false,
playlist: true,
playTitle: $current,
```

But "playTitle" is not working. I've looked at the MediaElement.js user guide and I think I should use play(). Maybe play($current)? Is it possible to make it easy?

Answer (score 0):

Where did you find playlist or playTitle options in the doc ?

You should use something like this, regarding to your link :

```
var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#player', /* Options */);

// Get track number you want to play, current should be a number    
var current = <?php echo $current; ?>;    

player.pause();
player.playTrack($('.mejs-playlist li').eq(current));
player.play();
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that, but I'll have to rename songs (1.mp3, 2.mp3...).
Playlist is an add on: https://github.com/duozersk/mep-feature-playlist

Comment: Look my edits, your addon provide some functions you can use to play a track in your playlist.